# How can I open a file with the standard text editor?

Tags: rust

My console based program has a config file which can be opened and edited in a text editor.

How would I open said config file with the default text editor? I know there is `std::process`, but I can't get it to work.

The program should be able to run on Windows, OS X and Linux systems.

Comment: "*but I can't get it to work*" - please [edit] your question to show what you tried and why it doesn't work. In this case if "not working" was an error like "no text editor installed", then no amount of code would be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`open` crate](https://crates.io/crates/open). It supports Windows, OS X and Linux. To open a text-file on your `C:` drive, you can use

```
extern crate open;

fn main() {
    open::that("C:\textfile.txt");
}
```

Comment: The function's name is... special.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree; it clearly should be `open::this`!

Comment: But that uses `xdg-open` or some equivalent. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use `$EDITOR` for console based programs?